# Function not displaying the answer of a calculation

Tags: c, function, switch-statement

I'm very new to this, I've tried everything, but I cant get it to work, it only shows "Invalid math operation" no matter what I change. Please help me solve this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int fnCalculate (int fn, int sn);

int main()
{
    int fn, sn;
    char op;
    printf("Enter 2 interger values and math operation [+] [-] [*] : ");
    scanf("%d %d %c", &fn, &sn, &op);
    printf("%d", fnCalculate(fn,sn));
    getch();
    return 0;

}
int fnCalculate (int fn, int sn)
{
char op;
switch(op){

case '+' : printf("%d + %d = %d", fn, sn, fn+sn);break;
case '-' : printf("%d - %d = %d", fn, sn, fn-sn);break;
case '*' : printf("%d * %d = %d", fn, sn, fn*sn);break;
default : printf("Invalid Math Operation");break;

}
}
```

Comment: you need to pass `op` into the function - its not a global..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to send operation character to the function. The `op` in function is uninitialized and holds a garbage value.

```
void fnCalculate (int fn, int sn, char op)
{
    switch(op){

    case '+' : printf("%d + %d = %d", fn, sn, fn+sn);break;
    case '-' : printf("%d - %d = %d", fn, sn, fn-sn);break;
    case '*' : printf("%d * %d = %d", fn, sn, fn*sn);break;
    default : printf("Invalid Math Operation");break;
    }
}
```

Call it like:

```
fnCalculate(fn,sn,op);
```

Also, it should return an `int` value. It is not returning anything, so there is another problem there. Or change the signature to `void` and just call the function, not in `printf`.

Comment: Oh, yes. Sorry about that.

Comment: suggest also change the return type to void in the example or at least return something in the example

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your function definition to accept the value of `op` also and while calling, you need to pass the value of `op`. Otherwise, in your function currently,

```
char op;
switch(op){
```

is trying to read an uninitialized automatic local variable which invokes undefined behavior.